# Subscription charges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm in the process of creating an app, which would work with a Freemium type of subscription.

I haven't had to handle payments before, so is a bit of a challenge, especially since all the resources I find seem to deal with only a checkout approach, you pay and off you go. Here is slightly different as the charges would be monthly and credit card info needs to be stored, and protected.

has anyone had to deal with this before? Any suggestions, gems, tutorials, resources are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to save yourself the trouble and go with one of the subscription billing services:

chargify, Spreedly, Cheddargetter, Recurly, Costify...

Answer (score 1):

For rolling your own, [ActiveMerchant](http://www.activemerchant.org/) is a great gem for interacting with payment gateways.

[Spreedly](http://spreedly.com/) is getting a lot of good press at the mo if you're happy to unload the responsibility of billing to a 3rd party.

Comment: @Pascal and idlefingers: I think since I'm new to this, it would make more sense to unload the responsibility to a 3rd Party as you seem to suggest. The point is to solve this in the short term, and if everything is ok, then i guess one can look at digging a bit deeper. Thanks for the suggestions guys!

Comment: If you do decide to roll your own later down the line, you should avoid storing any card data at all costs. Most good payment gateways will allow you to authorise a card and will give you a token which you can then use to authorise future payments (rather than storing and sending all the card details again). Even if you don't need to prove compliance, you should at least have a skim through this [PCI DSS compliance quick reference guide](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_ssc_quick_guide.pdf) to get an idea of what is right and wrong in this neck of the woods.